# Assigning line to second y axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a quite complex plot. The result should be a stacked and grouped bar plot with additional lines based on a second y axis. So far I managed to create the stacked and grouped bar plot (pseudo-grouped, enough for me) but I suffer at assigning the line part to the second y axis.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(
  DATE = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-15")
  , XXX_TY_T = c(20, 30, 25)
  , XXX_TY_C = c(10, 5, 15)
  , XXX_PY_T = c(15, 20, 20)
  , XXX_PY_C = c(20, 20, 15)
  , YYYY_TY_TD = c(0.7, 0.8, 0.75)
  , YYYY_PY_TD = c(0.4, 0.7, 0.6)
)

df_long <- df %>%
  gather(CATEGORY, VALUE, XXX_TY_T:YYYY_PY_TD) %>%
  mutate(CATEGORY2 = c(rep("XXX_TY", 6), rep("XXX_PY", 6), rep(NA, 6))
         , XAXIS = paste0(DATE, " | ", CATEGORY2))

df_long_bar <- df_long %>% filter(!(CATEGORY %in% c("YYYY_TY_TD", "YYYY_PY_TD")))
df_long_line <- df_long %>% filter(CATEGORY %in% c("YYYY_TY_TD", "YYYY_PY_TD")) %>%
  rename(LINE = VALUE) %>%
  mutate(CATEGORY2 = ifelse(CATEGORY == "YYYY_TY_TD", "XXX_TY", "XXX_PY")
         , XAXIS = paste0(DATE, " | ", CATEGORY2)) %>%
  filter(CATEGORY2 == "XXX_PY") %>%
  select(XAXIS, LINE)

df_long_plot <- left_join(df_long_bar, df_long_line, by = c("XAXIS")) 

ggplot(df_long_plot) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = XAXIS, y = VALUE, fill = CATEGORY), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  geom_line(aes(x = XAXIS, y = LINE), stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./40))
```

The result should look like this (drawn line ist not based on the data, just to clarify):

[image]

> How can I get this line into the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following with your final data frame:

1. Omit `NA` values from the data passed to `geom_line`;
2. Add a grouping variable to `geom_line`'s aesthetic mappings;
3. Transform the y-value (use the opposite transformation from the one used in `sec_axis`).

```
ggplot(df_long_plot, aes(x = XAXIS)) +         # put common aes mappings on top
  geom_col(aes(y = VALUE, fill = CATEGORY)) +  # geom_col() is equivalent to 
                                               # geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_line(data = . %>% na.omit(),
            aes(y = LINE * 40, group = 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./40))
```

I've removed the `position = "stack"` / `stat = "identity"` parameters from the code, as these are the default values for the respective geom functions anyway.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that your `barplot` works on categories, while your line plot should operate on numerical values. Thus, you have to transfrom your x values accordingly.

You transform your `XAXIS` to a factor first (with all the levels as seen in `df_long_bar`) and then transform it back to numeric. Since a second axis is finally a mere annotation, you have to scale `LINE` such that it is reprsented properly on the *first* axis.

```
ggplot() +
   geom_bar(data     = df_long_bar,
            aes(x    = XAXIS, 
                y    = VALUE, 
                fill = CATEGORY), 
            stat     = "identity", 
            position = "stack")+
   geom_line(data    = df_long_line, 
              aes(x  = as.numeric(factor(XAXIS,
                                        levels(as.factor(df_long_bar$XAXIS)))), 
                  y  = LINE * 40)) +
   scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 40))
```

[image: Bar-Line-Chart]